# Track links that causes 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I am trying to track all those link that causes 404.i tried  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on 404 page but it doesn't work for me .
NOTE: i don't wanna use google analytic API. Is there any other possible way

Comment: Are you using an Apache or IIS server?

Comment: Create a `.htaccess` file that will redirect to a 404 page on 404 error. From there you can do all the data capturing that you need to.

Comment: Add this code to your `.htaccess` file: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` and in the root of your code create a file called `404.php`. In that `404.php` file you can do all the handling of the error.

Comment: my page is redirecting to 404 but i want to track which link causes that. for that as i said i used "http_referer" on 404.php but failed

Comment: Have you tried looking at what the `$_SERVER` variable contains?

Comment: yes ! but it doesn't contain any info that could b used to detect the referer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105095/discussion-between-nomi-and-jacques-koekemoer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file that will redirect to a 404 page on 404 error. 
Add this code to your `.htaccess` file: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` and in the root of your code create a file called `404.php`. In that `404.php` file you can do all the handling of the error.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should have the URL that was requested in the browser.

Also make sure that you are loading the 404 page and not redirecting to the 404 page.